# Swapping old laptop ssd with ubuntu into a new laptop

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, swap

How can I swap my old ssd with ubuntu into a new laptop. I get the error "Reboot and select proper boot device"

Comment: Was the old laptop configured for Legacy/MBR or UEFI? Is the new laptop also set to match? Which version of Ubuntu is in use; 19.04 18.04, 16.04, other? Please click [edit] and put the info in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your device priority in your bios and if it's configured to UEFI. If it still doesen't work, try repairing your GRUB. You can use an Ubuntu installation disc or USB drive to do this. Boot into the USB drive and use the the Linux system to repair GRUB.

Comment: Yes the new laptop has Legacy bios and I believe the old laptop had UEFI bios. I tried converting the bios in the new laptop but it didn't seem to work .